# How can I model a nail polish bottle with a rounded top and a square solid glass bottom?

Tags: modeling, objects, glass

What's the best way to model a bottle that has a solid glass bottom like this one? I've already modelled the basic shape but I'm stuck as to how I deal with solid square base. Is it a case of extruding the model into itself and trying to follow the shape or maybe I should model the bottom separately and attach them?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exterior of the bottle makes a transition from rounded-square to circular profile:

[image]

..here, a loft, using *Bridge Edge Loops* between a plane with its corners <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> bevelled, and a duplicate of it, put through *Loop Tools > Circle*.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> Bevel the top circle to reference, scale the inside and extrude, to form the neck of the bottle. Give the bottle a *Solidify* modifier. Don't worry about the shell at the bottom of the bottle, it will be deleted. It's maybe more convenient to uncheck 'Fill Rim' in the modifier before applying it.. it will make selection simpler:

[image]

(Below left) With everything hidden, still in Edit Mode, create a UV sphere with 12 segments to match the existing profiles. We want a little less than a hemisphere, so, here, 7 rings. The top half is deleted, and the remainder adjusted to reference. <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> > *Flip* its normals. It's on the inside.

[image]

(Middle, above ) Now, the inner shell is un-hidden, its bottom face deleted,its bottom edge <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> slid upwards and scaled, making a nice- looking gap to be bridged, again using *Bridge Edge Loops*. (You may need to rotate the hemisphere through `360/24` degrees in Z, first, to avoid twist.)

(If you need to cut further loops to aid the transition, or just for more even density of faces, don't forget *Loop Tools > Circle* doesn't need to be applied at 100%.)

Unhide the rest of the bottle, bridge the rim, put in some bevels by hand to sharpen edges under subdivision, and put on your *Subdivision Surface* modifier:

[image]

You can probably render better than this.. I've got a feeling there's some fakery going on in your reference :)

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH- this is perfect !

Comment: Hi there, would you mind sharing the project file so I can see how you've built this? much appreciated if you could :)

Comment: @Joe Sure. I'll get to it tomorrow.. I think it's there, OK...

Comment: @JoeChapman   I'd deleted it, so had to reconstruct using my own instructions! 'That'll learn me', as they say down here in Devon, UK. Construction steps in 'Steps' collection .. here it is:  https://pasteall.org/blend/23d1d003ad70454e8d9b5415dce8635b

Comment: Incredible! you've been a massive help, thank you so much :)

Comment: @JoeChapman I've just noticed, strictly, the flat base needs tweaking for better subdiv.  Corner inset inner verts merged to form 'kite' quads, and then further insets?  I expect there are other tweaks to be made.. I'm sure you can feel your way through. You're welcome.